# Laravel: Combo Box show Information from Database on Edit entry (Crud)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

The topic question might be a little convoluted, so I will try to explain it better here.

Currently, I'm creating new users from an Administrator interface form (user request). In the form, there are the usual blank spaces for Username, Password, and the Unit the new user will be part of. Additionally, there is a combo box with fixed data selecting the kind of user this new entry will be (Normal user or Admin)

Code for reference

```html
<label for="" class="form-label">Rol</label>
<select name="rol" id="rol" class="form-control">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione un Rol</option>
    <option value="ROLE_ADMIN">Administrador</option>
    <option value="ROLE_USER">Usuario Normal</option>
</select>
```

Among the things this interface has to do, is the ability to Edit said users, and the idea is to leave the combo box selected of the value that it has on the DB, currently, I'm showing the combo box as is, forcing the user to select the "rol" over and over again.

I'm 70% sure an IF comparing data from DB to the combo box entries will do, but I cant figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-select the role using the `selected` attribute on the options. Assuming `$rol` holds the user's role:

```html
<select name="rol" id="rol" class="form-control">
    <option value="" disabled>Seleccione un Rol</option>
    <option value="ROLE_ADMIN" {{ $rol === "ROLE_ADMIN" ? 'selected' : '' }}>
        Administrador
    </option>
    <option value="ROLE_USER" {{ $rol === "ROLE_ADMIN" ? 'selected' : '' }}>
        Usuario Normal
    </option>
</select>
```